# oracle-jdk9-installer fails with HTTP 404

Tags: apt, java, oracle

When trying to install `oracle-jdk9-installer` package, I'm getting the HTTP 404 error:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 9...
--2017-06-24 09:15:02--  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/174/binaries/jdk-9-ea+174_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving download.java.net (download.java.net)... 72.247.184.89, 72.247.184.91
Connecting to download.java.net (download.java.net)|72.247.184.89|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-06-24 09:15:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
```

**Why is that and how it can be fixed?**

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 17.04 \n \l
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux intrepid 4.10.0-24-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:14:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: JDK 9 Early-Access Builds : http://jdk.java.net/9/ → Not a release version. 1) The URL can change. 2) The license must be accepted for every download. ..... So a direct link to `jdk-9-ea+174_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` seems to be an impossible thing.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04; normaly it works, so part 1 of Knud Larsens comment seems to by right. @Knud Larsen: it's possible to download from oracle automaticaly, e. g. with curl, if you provide a header. For curl the header would be `--header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" `

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, what worked for me was using [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/) to install, assuming you have SDKMAN installed it's as simple as:

```
sdk install java
```

At the time for me it installed *java 9.0.0-zulu*